# Vanilla JavaScript slideToggle to next item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to make dropdown item using vanilla js that has the same jQuery functionality with the `next` method. Because same class name not working with vanilla js

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.ms-dropdown');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  var next = this.nextElementSibling;

  if (next.style.display == "none") {
    next.style.display = "block";

  } else {
    next.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="ms-dropdown p-3">
  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto"><img src="images/tr-flag.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="col-auto ml-2">Budesliga <span>(16)</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
  asdfasdf
</div>
<div class="ms-dropdown p-3">
  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto"><img src="images/tr-flag.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="col-auto ml-2">Budesliga <span>(16)</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
  asdfasdf
</div>
```

Comment: IDK WHAT You mean but
IF you are trying to get all {.ms-dropdown } class 

querySelectorAll is the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MayBe Or Maybe not What you looking for

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-dropdown');

for(let i = 0 ; i < button.length;i++){
button[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  var next = this.nextElementSibling;

  if (next.style.display == "none") {
    next.style.display = "block";

  } else {
    next.style.display = "none";
  }
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ms-dropdown').forEach(function(item,i){
  item.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var next = this.nextElementSibling;
    next.style.display = next.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
});
```